# React native exporting variables

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was wondering how would I export this variable called dialCall to a different page. I'm also not sure how to call it from my app.js

Thanks!

```
import {Linking,Platform,TouchableOpacity,Text} from "react-native";
export default class MakeCall extends Component {

dialCall = (number) => {
 let phoneNumber = '';
 if (Platform.OS === 'android') { phoneNumber = `tel:${number}`; }
 else {phoneNumber = `telprompt:${number}`; }
 Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
};

//  Render(){
//         return(
//                 <TouchableOpacity
//                    style={{
//                    height: 30,
//                    width: 30,
//                    backgroundColor: "#329df4",
//                    alignItems: "center",
//                    justifyContent: "center",
//                    borderRadius: 5
//                    }}
//                  onPress={()=>{this.dialCall(123456789)}}
//                 >
//                 <Text>Phone</Text>
//                 </TouchableOpacity>
//               )
//   }

}
export {dialCall} ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with the below code.

```
import {Linking,Platform} from "react-native";

export const dialCall = (number) => {
 let phoneNumber = '';
 if (Platform.OS === 'android') { phoneNumber = `tel:${number}`; }
 else {phoneNumber = `telprompt:${number}`; }
 Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
};
```